# how to open port 3306

Tags: mysql, firewall

I'm trying to allow remote traffic to my mysql server.
I changed my bind address in my `mysqld.cnf` to `0.0.0.0`, and ran `sudo ufw allow 3306/tcp`  but I don't think my port 3306 is allowing traffic.

[image: Amazon EC2 security rule allowing 3306 access]

I'm trying to access the mysql server to store dev, staging and production.

Comment: running it on amazon ec2 instance should be good. ill add a picture.

Comment: Did you restart the mysql service after changing the configuration? How did you check whether it is listening?

Comment: i did. and I ran `netstat -l`

Comment: Check if you not have `--skip-networking` option when mysql daemon starts. How to check: `ps -ef | grep mysql` and check used options. What you got, when run `ss -tnpl | grep 3306`?

Comment: `ps -ef | grep mysql` returns `7290  7273  0 14:02 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mysql` `ss -tnpl | grep 3306` doesn't return anything

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the details you posted in your comments. It helps to keep our Q&A style tidy and could also bring more attention since an edited question gets bounced on the homepage. See also [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756/217657)

Answer (score 1):

Do this test from different sites in your infrastructure.

Install nmap like so,

```
sudo apt-get install nmap
```

and then try to scan the database server like so:

From localhost/same machine do

```
sudo nmap -sS 127.0.0.1
```

From the same network/other machine close by do (e.G.)

```
sudo nmap -sS 192.168.X.X
```

From the Internet do (e.G.)

```
 sudo nmap -sS 80.34.X.X
```

If the first and second test go well, you have a problem with your router. This problem is then not Ubuntu-related anymore, but a problem with the router you use to connect to the internet.

If the first test fails, your port is completly closed and you have to work on your mysql conf again.

If the first succeeds and the second one fails, recheck that mysql really listens to 3306. Do a

```
 sudo netstat -tlpn
```

Check that 0.0.0.0 is the source ip for port 3306/tcp. If that is the case you will have to recheck the settings with ufw. Disable the ufw for testing, to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Its an amazon ec2 instance. I don't control the router, but I can set up security rules.  nor do I have other devices on the same network.

Comment: Oh, so you have no neighbouring machines?  thats too bad. What happens, if you use nmap from your home (from the internet). Is there no port open? It should have ssh open, so you can connect. Does it list any other ports? Did you check netstat to see if mysql is set to 0.0.0.0?